# Trying to generate .ipa for both 32 and 64 bits

Tags: ios, xcode, architecture, 32bit-64bit, ipa

I developed an iOS app for iOS 5+ that is currently compiled for 32 bits. I'm using Xcode 6.1 and I've my project's `Architectures` value set to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` in `Build Settings`. If I change this to `Standard architectures`, Xcode says that I have to change the `Deployment target` from iOS 5.0 to at least iOS 6.1.

I've read in several places that it is possible to generate builds for both 32 and 64 bits. I need to keep this app to be backwards-compatible from iOS 5.0, but I don't find the way to achieve this. Maybe have I misunderstood and it is needed to generate two different `.ipa` files? How is this handled when submitting to `iTunes Connect`?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, iOS 5.0 is all but defunct.  I think you need to reevaluate how important it is to you to support back so far.  I don't think anybody was worried about 2.0 months after 5.0 came out.  In theory it should be possible if you know your way around unix and xcode command line tools, but any solution will likely not be worth the effort.

Comment: Also on iOS 5.1.1 support 64bit fat binaries, so the lowest versie you can target with a 32/63 bit is iOS 5.1.1

Comment: Thanks you both. So, would it be the recommendation to raise the `Deployment target` directly to iOS 6.1? On the other hand, does setting `Standard architectures` in Xcode 6.1 create `ipa` files only for 64 bits? Is it possible to generate an only `ipa` file for 32 and 64?

Comment: Standard Architectures includes both.  If you look at the list in includes armv7 (32-bit) and arm64 (64-bit).  armv7s was quietly dropped because there is only one device that gets a slight gain from it (iPad 4).  Not worth fattening up your binary for usually.